# Map port number in nginx to a custom hostname

Tags: docker, nginx, hostname, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Docker instance when booted up points `http://localhost:8080` in my browser to my dev PHP application. I want to amend the nginx configuration below to enable me to use a custom hostname like `backend.docker` in the browser rather than using `localhost:8080` - what is they way to do this via nginx?

```
server {

# Set the port to listen on and the server name
listen 80 default_server;

# Set the document root of the project
root /var/www/public;

# Set the directory index files
index index.php;

# Specify the default character set
charset utf-8;

# Setup the default location configuration
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

# Specify the details of favicon.ico
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# Specify the details of robots.txt
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

# Specify the logging configuration
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

# Specify what happens when PHP files are requested
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV development;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}

# Specify what happens what .ht files are requested
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
 }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add a `hosts` file entry on your host?

Answer (score 0):

Your host machine is pointing 8080 to the Docker's 80. You can create a custom hostname i.e. backend.docker in your host machines but for the port you need to setup reverse proxy unless it's 80 host to 80 in Docker.